# Having a different design and interactions between mobile and tablet devices can have a big impact from overall UX?

Tags: user-expectation

I have 2 design approach for a specific module 1 is for mobile and 1 is for tablet. The goal of this is for analyzation of the historical dates of the financial data.

**A. Mobile phone design** - Straight forward horizontal bar chart to differentiate each data from the previous periods.

[image: Mobile screen]

**B. Tablet Design** - This is to increase users interactions by providing more relevant information for analysis to filter the data and period based on their preferences. [image]

**Does it make sense from the users perspective do have different designs from the different screen? Does it not affect the learnability and familiarity on the app?**

Thank you

Comment: Do you have any info on what proportion of users will be switching between the two? If _most_ users use _either_ a tablet (or perhaps desktop), _or_ a mobile, and only a few will switch between the two, it may be less important that they look different.

Comment: "Does it make sense from the users perspective do have different designs from the different screen? " Yes.  Try not to make the differences too different however.

Comment: Just to note, the charts aren't just about design and look. Different chart types have different purposes... so I say go with the same chart for every device but allow some tweaking. For example, let the user scroll, resize or zoom the chart. Another option is limiting data: Show all 10 columns in larger screen, but show only 5 in smaller screens and let the user navigate (eg, see next 5 columns)

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to consistency and knowledge of application design, it is necessary to maintain the same system design (Typography, colors, spaces etc.)

The issue of functionality is also important - because once the logic is written - it can easily be adapted to all types of devices.

**I would recommend using a similar approach on any resolution**

- maintaining consistent clean code
- no sense of surprise / confusion by the user
- don't have to remember about different places in the application (in case of changes, you have to enter them 2x)

Currently, phones have great resolution, so designing a large number of functions should not be a problem

[image]

Credit for Iwona Sikora

Comment: Thanks for sharing your thought! I agree that consistency should be applied, but one thing in my mind is considering the other relevant information or actions that can be adopted on the larger screens. So that I'm torn between the consistency for the other screens.

Comment: Yes of course, If is need to be more functionalities/actions on larger screen it's should be apply and hide in smaller. 

Everything depends on the context, I recommend that You consult programmers and another designer on this issue :)

Answer (score 0):

With the understanding of two device screens holding same requirement - design components will differ to an extent due to real estate space. The differences lay within the design paradigm would make it familiar to the user. For example sort, filter can vary by interactive technique. But the larger sense of first-hand information should remain or depict in similar lines. This is how familiarity of both screens are addressed.

Familiarity - Through which the unified sense of experience is felt while moving between the devices. It means adding extra details on tablet (viz. content or text) against mobile device is not a bad ploy (As long as the design language is intact)

Learnability - Once user is under control (not alarmingly frustrated or questions the user interpretation or mental model) by means of familiarity the learnability will kick-in and user will evaluate if minor interaction (micro-interactions) would need to be learnt.

In summary, keep holistic sense of the app/screen in similar direction factoring for the miniscule interactions whether it would be tablet (landscape or portrait) vs. mobile (landscape or portrait).